# how to print the pathname of every file or folder recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is my code and error! please give me a hint

```
import os
def traverse(path, d):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        item = os.path.join(path, d)
        try:
            traverse(path,d)
        except:
            print (path)
```

my error:

```
traverse ("test",0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    traverse ("test",0)
  File "C:\Users\Phuchu\Desktop\Python\homework8.py", line 65, in traverse
    for item in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'test\\*.*'
```

Comment: What is your current directory? Is `test` a subdirectory of that?

Comment: you shouldn't call your function with `'*.*'` as a parameter for `d`

Comment: yes it is.And also test has couple of folder in it

Answer (score 1):

You may prefer to use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), which is more pythonic. It will turn the recursion into a simple to understand loop, and will manage traversing into directories for you.

Answer (score 1):

use os.walk

```
import os

def traverse(current_dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_dir):
        #print all files  recursively
        for file in files:
             print os.path.join(root,file)
         #print all folders recursively
        for dir in dirs:
             print os.path.join(root,dir)
```